# Width of Buttons in table varying with hyperlinks

Tags: button, width

I am filling a table  with buttons. In case the condition is true the button has enabled hyperlink and if false, the hyperlink is missing. To differentiate between Hyperlink enabled and not, i have applied Bootstrap class. But on width of the button with hyperlink is smaller than the button without hyperlink.

The HTML code is:-

```
if (true) {
     $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td><input class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;" type="button" name= "' . $trow . '"' . 'value= "' .  $trow . '"  id= "' .  $trow  . '" /></td>'; 
}else {
     $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td><input class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;"   name= "' . $trow . '"' . 'value= "' .  $trow . '"  id= "' .  $trow  . '" /></td>'; 
}
```

Please not the missing `view_class` in the button class under else condition.

The output screenshot is as follows:-

[image]

Is is possible to have equal fixed width buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Got it with little Hit & Try Method(HTM) :-

```
class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-block active view_data"
```

adding `btn-block` to the clause did the trick. Now all buttons in the column are of of same width.